# Animated interactive overlays on QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsScene, with QGraphicsView, as my "main" screen.
It zooms, pans, has scroll bars, etc.

I am trying to add interactive overlays on top (which are in fixed positions on the screen/viewport space). 
The only example I've seen of this online is Kuba Ober's, but it's just a TimerValue which changes in the upper right corner.
Originally, I put another widget on top of my main widget (which has the scene/view), but after reviewing Kuba's example, it seems this double widget is not recommended/may have issues.

What I want is to have animated panels, which contains clickable buttons/draggable objects/etc, slide in and out (like tabs that user clicks, panel slides out on top of scene below). I would also want fixed clickable items overlaid as well.

Using a layout with widgets doesn't give me the type of "overlay" effect that I want.

Any suggestions on the best way to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have written an application in which there are some animated panels on a `QGraphiscView`. I have created a layout that is child of the view (e.g. `layout = QHBoxLayout(graphicsView);`) and I have added my panels (that are `QWidget` subclasses) to the layout.

Comment: Thanks Fabio,  I created a QVBoxLayout, and when a user presses a key i dynamically create a qbutton and add it to the layout.  But the layout continues to readjust itself based on number of buttons and spacing. Which i know is what layouts do, is there a way to keep everything fixed. Im trying to create a "layers" panel, and each time the user adds a layer button i don't want the panel and its buttons to move slightly as the new button is added. any ideas?